# Finding word in PDF

Tags: robotframework

I would like to find some word after convert PDF.

1)I have 2 PDF at path C:\TRM\PDF    1.pdf and 2.pdf

- 1.pdf has word "ICG00058"
- 2.pdf has word "ICG00065"

2) Convert Pdf To Txt  at  ${detail_1}  already.

3) Suppose,  I don't know the word in 1.pdf and I want to check that
  1.pdf has ICG00058 or ICG00065.

I'm so sorry,If the question is not clear.
Please investigate this issue for me cause It's paramount important for my work.

```html
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library
Library         String
Library         Pdf2TextLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
Read PDF

    ${detail_1}     Convert Pdf To Txt              C:\\TRM\\PDF\\1.pdf
    LOG     ${detail_1} 
    ${ID_1}     Get Regexp Matches        ${detail_1}          ICG00058
    ${ID_2}     Get Regexp Matches        ${detail_1}          ICG00065
 Run Keyword And Ignore Error          $ID_1[0] in $detail_1      LOG   ${ID_1}
 Run Keyword If                        $ID_2[0] in $detail_1      LOG   ${ID_2}
```

ERROR:
Evaluating expression 'RF_VAR_ID_2 [0 ]in  RF_VAR_detail_2' failed: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword if you want to run python within your robot script, that is why you are seeing the error you have mentioned.

In your case though you could use the [Get Index From List](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#List%20Should%20Contain%20Value) and [List Should Contain Value](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#List%20Should%20Contain%20Value) keywords:

```
${matched_id_1}=    Get Index From List     ${ID_1}     0
Run Keyword And Ignore Error    List Should Contain Value    ${detail_1}    ${matched_id_1}

${matched_id_2}=    Get Index From List     ${ID_2}     0
Run Keyword And Ignore Error    List Should Contain Value    ${detail_1}    ${matched_id_2}
```

If you want to use the `List Should Contain Value` keywords as assertions just remove the [Run Keyword And Ignore Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error) keywords in the answer

Comment: After I   use keyword  Get Index From List     ${ID_1}     0.  I have faced like this ${matched_id_1} = -1   in log.   Expected should be  ICG00058.

Comment: If you get a result from regexp the second part is probably unnecessary since you just check the value you have already extracted from your file is in your file. Add the result you have in `${ID_1}` and `${ID_2}` in your question

Answer (score 0):

I used `pdfgrep` just like `grep` you can search for `regex` expressions in the pdf without any intermediate step.

I used it to look up ISBN numbers in the pdfs and automatically rename the filename to include the found ISBNs or write the filename and ISBN to an MySQL database.

If you don’t know how to write `regex` there are some online tools to test `regex` online until you find the right one to use.